# How do I parse ISO 8601 date without year using DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, datetime-format, iso8601, datetimeoffset, datetime-parsing

I need to parse ISO 8601 dates that does not contain a year and probably month component, such as:

```
--0412T102200Z
```

I am trying to use the following code which throws exception '*There must be at least a partial date with a year present in the input.*':

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("--0412T102200Z", "'--'MMdd'T'HHmmssZ",
           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

How do I parse such dates? Any chance to avoid replacing '--' with a year manually before parsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While substituting the year for dashes might be allowed in certain formats like [XML XSD Schemas](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/), that is technically not an ISO-8601 compliant value.

Ask yourself what this value *means* - it probably means "*every year* at this month, day, and time at UTC".  In other words, it's a recurrence pattern.

The .Net `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` types cannot store a recurrence pattern.  They are for representing a specific date and time.

So unfortunately, there is no way to parse this without a year.  You will first need to determine which year you want to apply the pattern to, replace the dashes manually with `String.Replace`, and *then* you can parse it.